# Bigrams with list as input using NLTK module

Tags: python, nltk

I have following list of which I'd like to obtain the equivalent but rearranged in bigrams:

```
filtered_words = ['friends', 'friend, 'know', 'hate', 'love', 'you?', 'like', 'name?']
```

Then, when applying the bigrams()-function, the following way:

```
list(bigrams(filtered_words))
```

I get: `'list' object is not callable.`

I also tried `list(bigrams([filtered_words]))`, with the same result.

Comment: For starters, your second item in your list has no `'` at the end. Check if this is the case on your side or the above is just an example.

Comment: `'list' object is not callable` usually means, that somewhere in your code a function is expected, but a list is passed (reproducible with `[]()`, e.g. treating a list as a function). Judging from the API docs of NLTK your code should work. Make sure the error is really coming from your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason why you might be getting this is because you used the reserved name `bigrams` as a list. For example, see following code.

```
In [9]: bigrams = [bigram for bigram in bigrams(filtered_words)]

In [10]: bigrams(filtered_words)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-32c8287373b9> in <module>()
----> 1 bigrams(filtered_words)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This produces a conflict because `bigrams` was imported without reference to its namespace *and then* was assigned another value, which confuses the program when it's called again. Naturally, `bigrams` is now a list, which is why calling it as a function returns an error which says that *it is not callable*. This is a common error when using `from nltk import *` or the like.

Also, even if you import the whole namespace, avoid naming your variables the same names as the functions you're using or will be using. That's bad programming.

TLDR: Import the namespace properly OR use another variable name OR just do both. The following should work fine.

```
In [11]: import nltk

In [12]: bigrams_list = [bigram for bigram in nltk.bigrams(filtered_words)]

In [13]: bigrams_list
Out[13]: 
[('friends', 'friend'),
 ('friend', 'know'),
 ('know', 'hate'),
 ('hate', 'love'),
 ('love', 'you?'),
 ('you?', 'like'),
 ('like', 'name?')]
```